# Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 anymore!

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, firmware

I've been struggling with my wifi for a week now. Since we changed router and provider(O2 box 6431), the connection doesn't work on Ubuntu anymore, yet it does work on windows (and also on ubuntu with other connections). The crazy thing is that it sometimes randomly works and then just stop after sleep mode and doesn't recover. One of my last attempts was to install another firmware

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source && sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

but now it fails connect to the router, while before I was connected but had internet didn't work.
I add further information here:

```
mario@ThinkPadMG:~$ ifconfig
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:66:d5:a9  
      inet addr:192.168.1.26  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3e97:eff:fe66:d5a9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2779028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1396404 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4100463259 (4.1 GB)  TX bytes:105833025 (105.8 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f3a00000-f3a20000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:667794 (667.7 KB)  TX bytes:667794 (667.7 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:88:14:f0:6a:28  
      inet6 addr: fe80::6e88:14ff:fef0:6a28/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6750 (6.7 KB)  TX bytes:7750 (7.7 KB)

mario@ThinkPadMG:~$ iwconfig
wwan0     no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

mario@ThinkPadMG:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

mario@ThinkPadMG:~$ nmcli nm
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled

mario@ThinkPadMG:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
```

Please help!!

[Update] paste.ubuntu.com/9912617
`dmesg | grep iwl` gives no output

[Update2] I used the command `echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and wifi was ok: I was on Mozilla, watched a video, did stuff and it worked. Then I didn't use my laptop for 10 minutes and now it only shows it's connected to the router, but no actual connection.
Using the command again, connection is back.

This is the result of `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlan0` : http://paste.ubuntu.com/9921077/

Wireless diagnostic script output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9912617/

Comment: According to the diagnostics you don't have a Wifi chipset from Broadcom, so all the `broadcom` and `b43` packages are useless in your case. The same diagnostics seem to report a working wireless connection with an IP address lease via DHCP and all. Does the problem persist? Can you reach the router (`ping 192.168.1.1`), a public internet host (e. g. `ping 8.8.8.8`), and resolve host names (e. g. `host google.com`)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Could broadcom driver interfere with iwlwifi driver ? Like you said, in the script it says he has intel chipset

Comment: If they interfere, that would be a bug. I never heard of that particular issue, but I'm no Linux wireless guru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if the router might be wireless n only, if so the next command and a reboot should fix `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

disable IPv6 in network manager by selecting ignore and add the terminal results for `dmesg | grep iwl` 
then add another change to the module
`echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Reboot with ethernet cable unplugged

Comment: I tried and rebooted, but still doesn't work... thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, run this in terminal and copy the contents of the wireless-info.txt it creates and paste it at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL it gives `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9912617/

Comment: It's working after reboot! I also tried sleep mode and then it worked when I resumed the system...seems like you solved it! @Jeremy31

Comment: Lets see what `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlan0` reveals

Comment: I added the information. It still goes on and off

Comment: Log into your access point and see if 11b/g/n is set and see if the country setting is correct

Comment: Do you mean in my network manager? Or what do you mean with logging into my access point? Hope this is not a stupid question

Comment: I guess you called it a router, you might be able to access the setup by entering 192.168.1.1 in your browser

Comment: Oh got it. I need a fu***ng password to enter the set up. I'll have to ask my flatmates. Thanks for your patience

Comment: I had no connection and I used the 'echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf' again. Now no wifi at all, doesn't even find routers. 'ifconfig' shows no wlan0

Comment: Try `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and delete the last line which should say `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N` then reboot

Comment: Ok, now I have at least WiFi back. No connection though

Comment: Reboot and hold the shift key until you see the grub menu.  Scroll down to advanced options or previous versions, press enter and see if you have kernel 3.13.0-37 and boot into that to see if there is any difference

Comment: I have Kernel 3.13.0-32 and -44, I booted into those but no difference

Comment: My router has a wifi/wps button: If I switch wifi off and then on, connection works.

Comment: I wonder if `sudo killall wpa_supplicant` might fix the problem as it did for a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1311257  The killall command will disconnect you momentarily but wifi should return

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Only one idea left `iwconfig` will show a MAC address after 'Access Point' go into network manager, select your connection go to BSSID and select the same MAC as the one you found in iwconfig, then save.  Possibly try 20 versus AUTO or 40 for the channel width

Comment: @Procope: It would be good to include relevant uncovered info in your question, so other people don't overlook it.

Comment: @Procope so the router is the real problem, it seems, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Laptop switches off WI-FI to save power, when its idle.

You can try disabling "Switch off wifi" option in Power Saving Mode, if its a Dell Laptop.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem with the o2box 6431. (Ubuntu 14.04, Samsung Ativ book)
after setting the router to "n-only" mode it suddenly worked

Comment: -1 If the supported revisions and frequency ranges of the IEEE 802.11 standard were the issue, it wouldn't work on other operating systems either.