# Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have exactly the same problem of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578535/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-14-04-anymore), however solution accepted as answer doesn't work. I also did all the commands in comment of that question but still no success.

The strange fact is when I use live cd of the same version of Ubuntu, I add the driver from "additional drivers". However after installing Ubuntu on HDD, in "additional drivers" I can find the missing driver(Broadcam Coporation:BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY) which under the name,it is written that "the device is not working.". Selecting the driver and "Apply changes" wont also affect.

`dmesg`

```
[    0.788962] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.788970] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: detected 2 ports
[    0.789002] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io base 0x000080e0
[    0.789052] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.789055] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.789057] usb usb3: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.789060] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-47-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.789062] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    0.789204] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.789212] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.789467] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.789474] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    0.789482] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: detected 2 ports
[    0.789511] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: irq 21, io base 0x000080c0
[    0.789561] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.789564] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.789566] usb usb4: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.789568] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-47-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.789570] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.1
[    0.789711] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.789719] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.789965] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.789971] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    0.789979] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: detected 2 ports
[    0.790000] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 20, io base 0x000080a0
[    0.790051] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.790054] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.790056] usb usb5: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.790058] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-47-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.790060] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    0.790200] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.790207] hub 5-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.790454] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.790461] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    0.790468] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: detected 2 ports
[    0.790489] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: irq 19, io base 0x00008080
[    0.790538] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.790541] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.790543] usb usb6: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.790545] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-47-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.790547] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.1
[    0.790687] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.790697] hub 6-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.790970] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.790976] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    0.790984] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: detected 2 ports
[    0.791004] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: irq 16, io base 0x00008060
[    0.791054] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.791057] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.791059] usb usb7: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.791061] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-47-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.791064] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.2
[    0.791203] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.791210] hub 7-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.791479] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.791486] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[    0.791495] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: detected 2 ports
[    0.791524] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: irq 18, io base 0x00008040
[    0.791574] usb usb8: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.791576] usb usb8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.791579] usb usb8: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.791581] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-47-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.791583] usb usb8: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.3
[    0.791722] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.791729] hub 8-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.791899] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBC,PNP0f13:MOUE] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.816235] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.816240] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.816426] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.818128] rtc_cmos 00:02: RTC can wake from S4
[    0.818284] rtc_cmos 00:02: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    0.818313] rtc_cmos 00:02: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    0.818323] i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.818415] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.818515] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.29.0-ioctl (2014-10-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.818536] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.818754] PCCT header not found.
[    0.818755] ACPI PCC probe failed.
[    0.818874] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.819019] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.819285] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.819299] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.819681] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.820873] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 8335c30cf45ac8874b83816192bf33dddcb532b6'
[    0.820894] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.823233] Key type trusted registered
[    0.827157] Key type encrypted registered
[    0.827166] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.827170] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.827200] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    0.828165]   Magic number: 0:332:227
[    0.828260] acpi PNP0200:00: hash matches
[    0.828323] rtc_cmos 00:02: setting system clock to 2016-01-27 11:14:33 UTC (1453893273)
[    0.828685] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.828687] EDD information not available.
[    0.828788] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    0.829389] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1408K (ffffffff81d27000 - ffffffff81e87000)
[    0.829392] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    0.829683] Freeing unused kernel memory: 256K (ffff8800017c0000 - ffff880001800000)
[    0.829878] Freeing unused kernel memory: 340K (ffff880001bab000 - ffff880001c00000)
[    0.840491] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
[    0.845303] systemd-udevd[102]: starting version 204
[    0.893547] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    0.894018] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168c/8111c at 0xffffc90004a82000, 00:26:9e:96:54:8a, XID 1c4000c0 IRQ 30
[    0.894021] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 6128 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    0.898564] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.898567] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.901416] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: SDHCI controller found [197b:2382] (rev 0)
[    0.901559] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: No vmmc regulator found
[    0.901562] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: No vqmmc regulator found
[    0.904753] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:06:00.1] using DMA
[    0.904777] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.2: SDHCI controller found [197b:2381] (rev 0)
[    0.904866] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.2: Refusing to bind to secondary interface.
[    0.909453] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    0.909942] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[    0.909975] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0200 32 slots 4 ports 3 Gbps 0x33 impl SATA mode
[    0.909978] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq sntf stag pm led clo pmp pio slum part ccc ems sxs 
[    0.912269] ssb: Found chip with id 0x4312, rev 0x01 and package 0x00
[    0.912287] ssb: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (cc 0x800, rev 0x16, vendor 0x4243)
[    0.912303] ssb: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (cc 0x812, rev 0x0F, vendor 0x4243)
[    0.912316] ssb: Core 2 found: PCMCIA (cc 0x80D, rev 0x0A, vendor 0x4243)
[    0.912329] ssb: Core 3 found: PCI-E (cc 0x820, rev 0x09, vendor 0x4243)
[    0.936177] scsi host0: ahci
[    0.943541] scsi host1: ahci
[    0.946519] scsi host2: ahci
[    0.946672] scsi host3: ahci
[    0.946793] scsi host4: ahci
[    0.946934] scsi host5: ahci
[    0.947015] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xda105000 port 0xda105100 irq 31
[    0.947019] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xda105000 port 0xda105180 irq 31
[    0.947021] ata3: DUMMY
[    0.947022] ata4: DUMMY
[    0.947025] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xda105000 port 0xda105300 irq 31
[    0.947028] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xda105000 port 0xda105380 irq 31
[    0.968347] firewire_ohci 0000:06:00.0: added OHCI v1.10 device as card 0, 4 IR + 0 IT contexts, quirks 0x10
[    0.968632] ssb: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:02:00.0
[    1.100030] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.228054] usb 4-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    1.236705] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0180
[    1.236711] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.236715] usb 2-4: Product: HP Webcam
[    1.236719] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Bison
[    1.236723] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 961230000000100
[    1.402136] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[    1.402143] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.402147] usb 4-1: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    1.402151] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: PixArt
[    1.408864] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.424461] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.424464] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.426339] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/0003:093A:2510.0001/input/input7
[    1.426503] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-1/input0
[    1.440048] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.441254] ata1.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HTS545032B9A300, PB3OC60F, max UDMA/133
[    1.441259] ata1.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    1.442622] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.442825] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HTS54503 C60F PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.443137] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.443139] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[    1.443212] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.443216] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.443258] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.468243] firewire_core 0000:06:00.0: created device fw0: GUID 00241b00fcfdaa01, S400
[    1.496138]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    1.496673] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.932098] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    1.934352] ata2.00: ATAPI: hp BD-ROM BC-5500S, 1.85, max UDMA/100
[    1.936718] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.938266] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            hp       BD ROM BC-5500S  1.85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.941659] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 6.5, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xa04751/0xa00000/0x0, board id: 0, fw id: 428212
[    1.945709] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 16x/16x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.945714] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.945884] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.945955] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.027000] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
[    2.264103] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.584099] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.911773] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.591472] random: init urandom read with 99 bits of entropy available
[    4.068180] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   12.204471] Adding 4159484k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4159484k FS
[   12.365246] systemd-udevd[291]: starting version 204
[   12.583217] hp_accel: laptop model unknown, using default axes configuration
[   12.583564] ACPI: Video Device [VGA] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   12.584639] ACPI Error: [_T_1] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20141107/dswload2-330)
[   12.584648] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20141107/psobject-224)
[   12.584652] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEGP.VGA_.LCD1.GBQC] (Node ffff88013b0b0938), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20141107/psparse-536)
[   12.584661] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEGP.VGA_.LCD1._BQC] (Node ffff88013b0b0910), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20141107/psparse-536)
[   12.584667] ACPI: Marking method _BQC as Serialized because of AE_ALREADY_EXISTS error
[   12.584672] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20141107/video-609)
[   12.586663] acpi device:09: registered as cooling_device2
[   12.586758] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:05/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8
[   12.596153] lis3lv02d: 8 bits sensor found
[   12.611489] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   12.622297] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   12.666220] ene_ir: chip is 0x3926 - kbver = 0x00, rev = 0xd2
[   12.666224] ene_ir: PLL freq = 1406
[   12.666225] ene_ir: KB3926D or higher detected
[   12.666238] ene_ir: Firmware regs: c0 00
[   12.666239] ene_ir: Hardware features:
[   12.666241] ene_ir: * Uses GPIO 40 for IR demodulated input
[   12.677532] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   12.693003] Registered IR keymap rc-rc6-mce
[   12.693222] input: ENE eHome Infrared Remote Receiver as /devices/virtual/rc/rc0/input9
[   12.698119] rc0: ENE eHome Infrared Remote Receiver as /devices/virtual/rc/rc0
[   12.706276] IR RC5(x/sz) protocol handler initialized
[   12.709107] IR RC6 protocol handler initialized
[   12.709485] IR NEC protocol handler initialized
[   12.712631] IR JVC protocol handler initialized
[   12.715519] IR Sony protocol handler initialized
[   12.718508] IR SANYO protocol handler initialized
[   12.724745] IR Sharp protocol handler initialized
[   12.729725] IR MCE Keyboard/mouse protocol handler initialized
[   12.745078] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 249 
[   12.747899] IR LIRC bridge handler initialized
[   12.749826] IR XMP protocol handler initialized
[   12.751347] input: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ene_ir) as /devices/virtual/input/input10
[   12.751580] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (ene_ir) registered at minor = 0
[   12.751602] ene_ir: driver has been successfully loaded
[   12.755047] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   12.795633] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[   12.807487] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[   12.809991] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047f (\PMBA) (20141107/utaddress-258)
[   12.809998] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   12.810002] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000050f (\GPIO) (20141107/utaddress-258)
[   12.810006] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   12.810066] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   12.811834] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   12.814299] sound hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0xf/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   12.814306] sound hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0xd/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   12.814308] sound hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   12.814311] sound hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   12.814313] sound hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[   12.814315] sound hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   12.814318] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x18
[   12.814320] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0xb
[   12.824203] input: ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer as /devices/platform/lis3lv02d/input/input12
[   12.824814] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   12.841349] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   12.841448] input: HDA Intel Front Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   12.845879] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[   12.876238] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[   12.876255] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2062, Revision 2, Version 0
[   12.903667] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
[   12.989042] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   12.992132] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[   12.992136] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[   12.999008] CRAT table not found
[   12.999013] Finished initializing topology ret=0
[   13.000242] kfd kfd: Initialized module
[   13.000956] checking generic (c0000000 300000) vs hw (c0000000 10000000)
[   13.000960] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from VESA VGA
[   13.001014] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   13.004252] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV710 0x1002:0x9553 0x103C:0x3628).
[   13.004273] [drm] register mmio base: 0xDA000000
[   13.004275] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[   13.004405] ATOM BIOS: BR34694.002
[   13.004598] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[   13.004601] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[   13.004604] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=256M
[   13.004605] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[   13.008065] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 2007028 kiB
[   13.008070] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   13.008078] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   13.008114] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[   13.008116] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   13.008149] [drm] Loading RV710 Microcode
[   13.065626] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.734:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.065635] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.734:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.065641] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.734:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.066138] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.734:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.066147] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.734:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.066404] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.734:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.068592] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.738:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=397 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.068602] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.738:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=397 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.068608] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.738:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=397 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.069097] audit: type=1400 audit(1453893285.738:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=397 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.071153] gpio_ich: GPIO from 435 to 495 on gpio_ich
[   13.072965] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   13.072989] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   13.073010] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   13.073021] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   13.073025] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
[   13.073027] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
[   13.073030] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   13.085316] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input15
[   13.384586] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   13.469497] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   13.469502] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   13.469504] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   13.469507] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   13.469510] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   13.469512] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   13.469514] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   13.469517] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   13.533904] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[   13.543606] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[   13.543677] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   13.543682] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800b85dfc00
[   13.543685] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800b85dfc0c
[   13.544693] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c598 and cpu addr 0xffffc90004e1c598
[   13.544697] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   13.544698] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   13.544700] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   13.544748] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   13.544783] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   13.591302] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   13.591311] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   13.664834] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   13.673213] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   13.687129] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam (5986:0180)
[   13.691173] input: HP Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input16
[   13.692337] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   13.692341] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   13.766271] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   13.766279] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   13.766710] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   13.766735] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   14.412187] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[   14.413983] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
```

Comment: lspci | grep -i wireless also results in nothing

Comment: That is obviously should not return anything. Run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: You need to install `firmware-b43-installer` or `bcmwl-kernel-source` depending on what exactly the adapter is.

Comment: thanks for comments. `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` results in
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1508]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge`

Comment: So read the duplicate link and install the firmware.

Comment: that is what I am doing. sorry for duplicate question